# Remote Desktop PC over LAN through a web browser

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, browser, remote-access, remote-control

My laptop runs Windows 7 Ultimate. This morning I found out my laptop's screen was damaged and my office work was hindered considerably. I can only get the screen replaced after a few days and things get back to normal. Up till then, I need to get along with this broken screen somehow. I managed to get an external monitor to work with during office hours. But I need a solution when I get back to my hostel.

Is there a way to control my laptop/PC over LAN (I don't trust the internet connection in my hostel). All I have is an Android phone. The most preferable solution would be to control my laptop through a web browser as it wouldn't need extra installations on my phone (which is a bit low on memory). Although controlling via web browser is preferable, other suggestions are welcome as well.

Thanks!

Comment: @zain.ali: I connect to the internet via a router installed in my room. Both, my phone and my laptop are on the same network. But the internet speed is a bit dizzy back there. Hence I would to know if there is a LAN oriented solution to my problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I know you are low on space, but I use RD Client by Microsoft. It's free on the play store.

The size does make it tricky but there are options to help.

I also found the 'hackers' keyboard to be a good choice if coding.

Obviously you'll need to have already configured your PC to allow incoming connections.

If you haven't, you can try to set this up "blindly". Start PC. When you feel it is has loaded and you've logged in:

1. Hit the start button on your keyboard
2. Type in `view advanced` and press enter. Wait a few seconds.
3. Then <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>
4. Press <kbd>right</kbd> 2 times
5. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> 4 times
6. Press <kbd>down</kbd> 3 times
7. Press <kbd>up</kbd> once
8. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> 5 times
9. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Install Cloud Server from NoMachine on your laptop. You will need to know your IP. Install NoMachine for Android on your phone (it's optimized for tablets so you will need to download it from their own site rather than the Play store). Open your browser and type in the IP of your laptop.

Comment: ... How does the OP do this when they can't use their laptop ?!!?